# Incorrect value in decibel measurement AVFoundation

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I get on the output wrong decibel value when silent get 0.00 if I create noise goes up to 0.02 - 0.03. Something I do wrong, because I measured with another application with silence, I get about 20 db, with noise about 50 db.
I hope you can tell me what needs to be fixed.

```
struct NoiseMeterView: View {

    let audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder
    @State var timer: Timer?
    @State var decibels: Float = 0

    init() {
        let audioFileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("audio.m4a")
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFileURL, settings: settings)
        } catch let error {
            fatalError("Error creating audio recorder: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Noise Level: \(String(format: "%.2f", decibels)) dB")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            Button(action: {
                if timer == nil {
                    startMetering()
                } else {
                    stopMetering()
                }
            }) {
                Text(timer == nil ? "Start" : "Stop")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }

    func startMetering() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.record)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error setting up audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.record()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { _ in
                audioRecorder.updateMeters()
                var decibels = audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0)
                decibels = min(max(decibels, -120), 0)
                self.decibels = pow(10, (decibels &#x2F; 20))
            }
    }

    func stopMetering() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        audioRecorder.stop()
    }
}
```

Need to make the range from 0 to 120 dB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense:

```
var decibels = audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0)
decibels = min(max(decibels, -120), 0)
self.decibels = pow(10, (decibels / 20))
```

This is converting decibels to an amplitude fraction (i.e. it converts the logarithmic value into a linear value), which is the opposite of what you suggest you want want. Given what you've described, the code you probably mean is:

```
var decibels = audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0)
decibels = min(max(decibels, -120), 0)
self.decibels = decibels + 120  // <<---
```

That will put the range [-160, -120] at 0dB, and the 0 peak at 120dB as you said you want. dB are always ratios, so you can shift them around and declare anything yow want to be zero. There is no universal definition of "0dB." There are many definitions depending on what you're doing.

The output of `peakPower` is in dBFS, which means that 0dB is "the largest signal the microphone can output," and -160dB is "the smallest signal the microphone can output." These do not necessarily correspond to specific SPL (sound pressure level) measurements which is what you're probably looking for. Different microphones can have different sensitivities and ranges. I'm not aware of any documented calibration for iPhone microphones, so you may need to do that yourself with a sound pressure meter. (When I've built these kinds of things, it was always for custom hardware; I've never needed it for the built-in microphone.)

The values you're describing (20dB for a quiet room and 50dB for normal conversation) match the [dBSPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure) scale, which is very common. It's possible that your "other app" is using [A-weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting) which is a more accurate way to measure how sound impacts human hearing, but it's probably just using dBSPL since that's much easier to compute. You just need to get a SPL meter and work out the offset to add. [ResearchKit](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/main/ResearchKit/ActiveTasks/splMeter_sensitivity_offset.plist) includes the following hard-coded offsets, but I haven't quite worked out how they're used in the code, and I'm a little surprised that all iPhone microphones would have the same sensitivity (but it's possible):

```
<dict>
    <key>iPhone</key>
    <real>-23.3</real>
    <key>iPod touch</key>
    <real>-23.3</real>
    <key>iPad</key>
    <real>-29.3</real>
</dict>
```